# $p(x)=x^{10}+a_1x^9+\cdots+a_{10}$ be a polynomial with real coefficients

Tags: real-analysis

I came across the following problem that says:

> Let $p(x)=x^{10}+a_1x^9+\cdots+a_{10}$ be a polynomial with real  coefficients. Suppose $p(0)=-1$, $p(1)=1$, $p(2)=-1$. Let $R$ be the number of real zeros of $p(x).$ Then which of the following must be true?
>   $$1)\ R \geq 4\qquad 2)\ R= 3\qquad 3)\ R= 2\qquad 4)\ R= 1$$

It is seen that  $p(0)=-1 <0$ and $p(1)=1>0.$ So there exists at least one real zero of $p(x)$ between $0$ and $1.$ Also $p(1)=1>0$ and $p(2)=-1<0$. So there exists at least one real zero of $p(x)$ between $1$ and $2.$ Further I notice that $p(1)=1$ gives $\sum_{i=1}^{10} a_i =0.$ Also, $p(0)=-1$ gives $a_{10}=-1$ and $p(2)=-1$ gives $2^{10}+a_12^9+\cdots+a_{10}=-1. $ But still I am not sure what conclusion can be drawn from these information.Can someone point me in right direction? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: What was wrong with the hints you already received?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First show that $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}p(x)=+\infty.$
Then it follows that $\exists x_1<0 :P(x_1)>0$. Since $p(0)<0$ there is a root between $x_1$ and $0$. In the same manner you can show that there is a root between $2$ and $x_2$ for some $x_2>2$.

Comment: Sir,I still can not understand it.Can you explain little bit more?

Comment: Since $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\pm\infty}p(x)=+\infty\Rightarrow \exists x_1<0, x_2>2: p(x_1),p(x_2)>0$. Now?

Comment: It means there exists no reals roots in $( \infty,0)$ or $(2,\infty).$ So all real roots of $p(x)$ lie in $(0,2)$ and total no.of real roots is $2.$ Am I right?

Comment: I think I have got it.So option $1$ should be the right choice.

Comment: @user33640: Right!

Answer (score 2):

Good start, but also note that the leading coefficient is $1$. What does that tell you about $$\lim_{x\to\pm\infty} p(x)\ ?$$

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is even degree polynomial and there exist a $x<0$ is positive then $(x,0)$ has a root. Then at least $4$ real root.